# ballerina: passing parameters to client request

Tags: http, ballerina

Is there a way to pass a variable value to a client request. Following is my code and it works fine when the value is hard coded.

```
endpoint http:Client gitClientEndpoint {
    url: "https://test.com"
};

function main(string... args) {
    var response = clientEndpoint->get("/users/Alex92");
```

Instead of hard coding "Alex92" I want to pass it as a string variable.

I tried the following

```
function main(string... args) {
    string userName = "Alex92";
    var response = clientEndpoint->get("/users/:userName");
```

But this does not work. Could anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String concatenation:

```
var response = clientEndpoint->get("/users/"+userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is you are trying to access a defined variable within an immutable.try the stranded string concatenation to resolve the problem.

```
function main(string... args) {
    string userName = "Alex92";
    var response = clientEndpoint->get("/users/"+userName);
```